# Create instanceprofile with CDK and Python

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I am new to cdk and trying to create an instance profile with CDK+Python with the following code. I have already created the Role (gitLabRunner-glue) successfully thru CDK and wanting to use it with the intance profile. However, when i run the following code, i get an error `gitLabRunner-glue already exists`

Can somebody please explain what am i missing ?

```
from aws_cdk import core as cdk
from aws_cdk import aws_glue as glue
from aws_cdk import aws_ec2 as _ec2
from aws_cdk import aws_iam as _iam

class Ec2InstanceProfile(cdk.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        # role = _iam.Role(self, "instanceprofilerole", role_name="gitLabRunner-glue",
        #              assumed_by=_iam.ServicePrincipal(service='ec2.amazonaws.com'))


        ec2gitLabRunnerinstanceprofile = _iam.CfnInstanceProfile(
            self,
            "ec2gitLabRunnerinstanceprofile",
            instance_profile_name="ec2-gitLabRunner-glue",
            roles=["gitLabRunner-glue"] # also tried with this[role.role_name]
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your AWS account already have a role with that name in it?

the Cfn Functions in cdk represent constructs and services that have not been fully hooked into all that is CDK. As such, they often don't do things that others would - where as a CloudFormation Template for the instance profile may just hook into the existing role, the coding in the back of this cfn function may go ahead and create a role item in the template output.

if you do a cdk synth, look in your cdk.out directory, find your cloudformation template, then do a search for gitLabRunner-glue - you may find there is a AWS::IAM::ROLE being created, indicating when CloudFormation attempts to run based of the template created by cdk it tries to create a new resource and it cant.

You have a couple options to try:

1. As you tried, uncomment the role again and use role.role_name but name the role something else or, as CDK recommends, don't include a name and let it name it for you
2. search your aws account for the role and delete it
3. If you absolutely cannot delete the existing role or cannot create a new one with a new name, then import the role, using (based off your imports)

   role = _iam.Role.from_role_arn(self, "ImportedGlueRole", role_arn="arn:aws:of:the:role", add_grants_to_resources=True)

be wary a bit of the add_grants_to_resources - if its not your role to mess with cdk can make changes if you make that true and that could cause issues elsewhere - but if its not true, then you have to update the Role itself in the aws console (or cli) to accept your resources as able to assume it.

Comment: yes, I had the role existing in my account. We are using ALZ and have to follow a certain naming convention to spin up resources. Hence, I can't let cdk create an instance profile behind the scenes with its own naming convention. I was also not able to use the existing role as a string in my code above. So I ended up deleting the existing role and creating the instance profile and role in the same code block. However, the desired design was that role to be created separately as an individual class and then reference it in the instance-profile class as an existing role.

Comment: that's still possible, you will just have to link the two stacks. you can set the role as an self variable in the stack and reference it outside - even going so far as to pass it into another stack (though i would make both stacks NestedStacks and put them in a 3rd common stack for the entire app - referencing stack constructs between top level (non nested) stacks can lead to difficulties in deployment when one stack cannot be updated because it would affect another.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a working example, because, I remember I tried this approach too and it didn't work for me. Perhaps, I was missing something...TIA

Comment: I don't have anything on a public git, as my cdk work is all on my companies enterprise git, but as a quicky...

https://imgur.com/a/o6r4gDS

something like that

You still either need to ahve the role NOT created before by anything other than the CDK stack that is creating it or use iam.Role.from_attributes or from_arn

Answer (score 1):

I made it work like this, not the desired model though, but given the limitations of cdk, i couldn't find any other way.

```
from aws_cdk import core as cdk
from aws_cdk import aws_glue as glue
from aws_cdk import aws_ec2 as _ec2
from aws_cdk import aws_iam as _iam

class Ec2InstanceProfile(cdk.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        boundary = _iam.ManagedPolicy.from_managed_policy_arn(self, "Boundary",
                                                           "arn:aws:iam::${ACCOUNT_ID}:policy/app-perm-boundary")

        # role = _iam.Role(self, "instanceprofilerole", role_name="gitLabRunner-glue",
        #              assumed_by=_iam.ServicePrincipal(service='ec2.amazonaws.com'))

        ec2_gitlabrunner_glue = _iam.Role(
            self, 'ec2-gitlabrunner-glue',
            role_name='gitLabRunner-glue',
            description='glue service role to be attached to the runner',
            # inline_policies=[write_to_s3_policy],
            assumed_by=_iam.ServicePrincipal('ec2.amazonaws.com'),
            permissions_boundary=boundary
        )

        ec2gitLabRunnerinstanceprofile = _iam.CfnInstanceProfile(
            self,
            "gitLabRunnerinstanceprofile",
            instance_profile_name="gitLabRunner-glue",
            roles=["gitLabRunner-glue"]
    )
```